# Aggregating a table based on one column and then joining it with another table

Tags: postgresql

I am working with the following two tables;

Table 1

```
Key          |Clicks |Impressions
-------------+-------+-----------
USA-SIM-CARDS|55667  |544343     
DE-SIM-CARDS |4563   |234829     
AU-SIM-CARDS |3213   |232242     
UK-SIM-CARDS |3213   |1333223    
CA-SIM-CARDS |4321   |8883111    
MX-SIM-CARDS |3193   |3291023
```

Table 2

```
     Key          |Conversions |Final Conversions|Active Sims
 -----------------+------------+-----------------+-----------
 USA-SIM-CARDS    |456         |43               |4
 USA-SIM-CARDS    |65          |2                |1
 UK-SIM-CARDS     |123         |4                |3
 UK-SIM-CARDS     |145         |34               |5
```

The goal is to get the following output;

```
Key          |Clicks |Impressions|Conversions|Final Conversions|Active Sims
-------------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-----------
USA-SIM-CARDS|55667  |544343     |521        |45               |5
DE-SIM-CARDS |4563   |234829     |           |                 |
AU-SIM-CARDS |3213   |232242     |           |                 |
UK-SIM-CARDS |3213   |1333223    |268        |38               |8
CA-SIM-CARDS |4321   |8883111    |           |                 |
MX-SIM-CARDS |3193   |3291023    |           |                 |
```

**The most crucial part of this function involves aggregating the second table based on conversions**

I would then I imagine execute this with an inner join.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take this in two steps then:

1) Aggregate the second table:

```
SELECT Key, sum(Conversions) as Conversions, sum("Final Conversions") as FinalConversions, Sum("Active Sims") as ActiveSims FROM Table2 GROUP BY key
```

2) Use that as a subquery/derived table joining to your first table:

```
SELECT 
    t1.key,
    t1.clicks,
    t1.impressions,
    t2.conversions,
    t2.finalConversions,
    t2.ActiveSims
From Table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Key, sum(Conversions) as Conversions, sum("Final Conversions") as FinalConversions, Sum("Active Sims") as ActiveSims FROM Table2 GROUP BY 2) t2
        ON t1.key = t2.key;
```

As an alternative, you could join and then group by as well since there isn't any need to aggregate twice or anything:

```
SELECT 
    t1.key,
    t1.clicks,
    t1.impressions,
    sum(Conversions) as Conversions, 
    sum("Final Conversions") as FinalConversions, 
    Sum("Active Sims") as ActiveSims
From Table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.key = t2.key
GROUP BY t1.key, t1.clicks, t1.impressions
```

The only other important thing here is that we are using a LEFT OUTER JOIN since we want all record from Table1 and any records from Table2 that match on the key.